# Error installing numpy, matplotlib, pandas, IPython and seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda

I am using python version 3.6.1 on a Windows machine.

I also installed Anaconda Python 3.7 version 64-bit Graphical installer.

I tried to install numpy, matplotlib, pandas, IPython and seaborn, but getting an error
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy"

The command for numpy:

```
Python –m pip install numpy
```

It return these messages::

```
Collecting numpy
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object 
at 0x000001400A0CE4A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)'
: /simple/numpy/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 
:
:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

How can I fix this installation issue ?
Thank you.

**Edit:**

This works:

```
Python –m pip install numpy --proxy http://MyCompanyProxy:Port/
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815784/python-pip-raising-newconnectionerror-while-installing-libraries ?

Comment: That looks like the solution, I would mark a duplicate, but it only provides answer for linux -- whatever the /etc/resolv.conf maps to on Windows might be the answer

Comment: if you have anaconda installed then you should use conda install  for installing packages

Comment: @Rarblack conda is often missing packages available with pip however

Comment: if you have anaconda you should already have pandas numpy and etc

Comment: The packages you get from PyPI when installing via pip actually come from https://files.pythonhosted.org - you should check if that site can be accessed. If it resolves and/or comes up in a browser you may have a proxy problem you need to teach pip how to overcome.

Comment: ping google.com returns "ping request could not find host google.com". Ping 8.8.8.8 returns "Request timed out". Even though I have installed anaconda, it doesn't look like I have numpy, panda, etc, because when I type "import numpy" on python, I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'". Do I need to reboot my machine after installing anaconda ? files.pythonhosted.org comes up. My company does use proxy.

Comment: I have edited the original posting with the solution. Thank you all for your help