# under wHAT circumstances would pip installation of python packages fail

Tags: python, installation, pip, pybind11

I was using command "pip install pybind11" in windows command prompt to install pybind11 library (https://pypi.org/project/pybind11)
to my company laptop. But the pip install failed for no logical reason.

I recieved error massage as shown in the screenshot below[image: Error Messages]. In comparison, I could  install it in my personal laptop where I have administrator right, though I was not asked to verify I'm administrator.

I have Anaconda installed in my company laptop, for which I have no administrator rights. (Anaconda3 + Python 3.6.1)

I encountered errors for the installation, even if I tried two different types of commands as shown in the screenshots below.

addition: I'm using VPN network in my company laptop.

Can someone please help me? thank you very much!

Comment: i think this would help u <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815784/python-pip-raising-newconnectionerror-while-installing-libraries> sorry if i am wrong

Comment: thank you I will try it out. im using  VPN connection in my company laptop so the suggestion on your link looks promising:)

Answer (score 0):

could be related to proxy issues, you might want to define your proxy in a .condarc file (see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/)