# Python pip installation

Tags: python, pip, imgkit

I have the python version 3.8.5 installed + pip.
Now I would like to install the package imgkit from pypi with pip install imgkit.

And this happens:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A0FF25DE50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/imgkit/`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imgkit (from versions: none)
```

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for imgkit
```

So could somebody please help me with this installation?

Comment: It looks like your machine can't resolve the hostname from pip where it tries to get the imgkit package from.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean

Can you run for example `nslookup pypi.org` in a terminal and check if you can resolve the IP behind pypi.org 

If not there seems to be something wrong with your local DNS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip raising NewConnectionError while installing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815784/python-pip-raising-newconnectionerror-while-installing-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a comment but I don't have the reputation just yet. From what I have searched through, I think this is a connection issue, are you using VPN while trying to install this package?

Also this link might help you solve your problem:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424