# Django "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused" error when connecting to django API via python script

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this basic Django API that I can access through the browser at `https://127.0.0.1:8000/norm/status/`; however, when I use python script to connect to it, I keep getting multiple errors.

This is the python script:

```
BASE_URL='https://127.0.0.1:8000'
ENDPOINT='norm/status/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

def get_resource():
    resp=requests.get(BASE_URL+"/"+ENDPOINT,  verify=False, headers=headers)
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())
get_resource()
```

The errors I see:

> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f80f8286490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /norm/status/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f80f8286490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

I am running the Django server inside a docker container and I am not sure if it has anything to do because of that. I really appreciate if someone can help me debug this.

I tried using django-cors-headers and also HTTPAdapter libraries but it didn't work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52815784/16770846) work for you?